# D3: Day names on x-axis: Invalid value for <text> attribute x="NaN"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 area chart showing values over time. Along my x-axis, I have 1-7 relating to days of the week. I want to replace these with mo, tu, we, etc etc etc

```
this.g.selectAll(".xLabel")
    .data(_this.x.ticks(6))
    .enter().append("svg:text")
    .attr("class", "xLabel")
    .text(String)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return _this.x(d) })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .attr("opacity", .5);
```

I thought this could be easily achieved by replacing

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return _this.x(d) })
```

with

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return _this.x(_this.arrDays[d]) })
```

(with _this.arrDays being a simple ["mo", "tu",......] array) but this is giving me the following error:

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute x="NaN"

Anyone care to shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted with:

```
this.g.selectAll(".xLabel")
    .data(_this.x.ticks(6))
    .enter().append("svg:text")
    .attr("class", "xLabel")
    .text(function(d) {return _this.arrDays[d-1]}) //changed this line
    .attr("x", function(d) { return _this.x(d) })
    .attr("y", "0")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .attr("opacity", .5);
```